# How to export selection as an image in GIMP?

Tags: gimp

I am new to GIMP. Imported an image, selected the relevant part using scissor tool, created a new channel out of this selection but how to export it? Right clicking on the channel does not give an option to save or export, File > Export exports the whole original image and not the selection.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Save selected portion of image in GIMP as PNG](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/132879/save-selected-portion-of-image-in-gimp-as-png)

Answer (score 5):

The quickest for me was to select something, then Edit->Paste As->New Image, then export from that new image. It doesn't even have to become a new channel or layer along the way.

Comment: Thx, super. With your help I do: select -> ctr+c -> ctrl+shift+v -> ctrl+shit+e

Answer (score -1):

Select your required area

Invert Selection

Delete

Invert Selection (to re-select your desired area)

Image-> Crop to selection

Export

Undo all above to return to original image

Repeat for each required area export